# Align <div> elements side by side

Tags: css, html, alignment

I know this is a rather simple question, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.   I have two links which I've applied a background image to.  Here's what it currently looks like (apologies for the shadow, just a rough sketch of a button):

[image]

However, I want those two buttons to be side by side.  I can't really figure out what needs to be done with the alignment.

**Here's the HTML**

```
<div id="dB"}>
    <a href="http://notareallink.com" title="Download" id="buyButton">Download</a> 
</div>
<div id="gB">
    <a href="#" title="Gallery" onclick="$j('#galleryDiv').toggle('slow');return false;" id="galleryButton">Gallery</a>     
</div>
```

**Here's the CSS**

```
#buyButton {
    background: url("assets/buy.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    display:block;
    height:80px;
    width:232px;
     text-indent:-9999px;
}
#buyButton:hover{
width: 232px;
height: 80px;
background-position: -232px 0;
}
#buyButton:active {
width: 232px;
height: 80px;
background-position: -464px 0;
}

#galleryButton {
    background: url("images/galleryButton.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    display:block;
    height:80px;
    width:230px;
     text-indent:-9999px;
}
#galleryButton:hover{
width: 230px;
height: 80px;
background-position: -230px 0;
}
#galleryButton:active {
width: 230px;
height: 80px;
background-position: -460px 0;
}
```

Comment: The first that comes to mind by just reading the title is `float:left;`

Comment: @JCOC611: Applying `float:left;` to both `div`s did it perfectly.  Can you post your comment as an answer?  Thanks!

Comment: And the second is `display: inline-block;` but it's less well supported...

Comment: float:left inside a container would work, but I would try using two <span> tags instead of <div>s for the buttons.

Comment: As already mentioned, adding float: left; to #buyButton and #galleryButton, then add another element with clear: both; to clear the floating.

Why using divs (block elements) to wrap <a> ?

Comment: @ludeesign:  I don't know why I wrapped them.  I originally wasn't, but with this problem I wrapped them for no reason I guess.  Removing the divs made no difference with `float:left;` so thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Apply `float:left;` to both of your divs should make them stand side by side.

Comment: Am I mistaken, or does a `clear:both;` need to go in there somewhere? I've never been the CSS savant but seems typical when I see floats to see clears as well.

Comment: `clear:both` will do exactly the opposite. "Elements after the floating element will flow around it. To avoid this, use the clear property."

Comment: @JCOC611: Ah, so clear usually follows when you want a momentary float ability? Makes sense. Thanks for the lesson. ;-)

Comment: Just to be "clear," (horrible, I know), you would need to use `<br style="clear: both;" />` if you had a third div which you wanted beneath the two which were aligned.

Comment: @Tass you need only have your third div like this: `<div style="clear: both;">...</div>` (no br required)

Answer (score 222):

## Beware `float: left`…

### …there are many ways to align elements side-by-side.

Below are the most common ways to achieve two elements side-by-side…

## Demo: [View/edit all the below examples on Codepen](https://codepen.io/beau/pen/odbrRa)

---

## Basic styles for all examples below…

Some basic css styles for `parent` and `child` elements in these examples:

```
.parent {
  background: mediumpurple;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid indigo;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

---

[image: float:left]

Using the `float` solution my have unintended affect on other elements. (Hint: You may need to use a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/101290).)

html

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child float-left-child'>A</div>
  <div class='child float-left-child'>B</div>
</div>
```

css

```css
.float-left-child {
  float: left;
}
```

---

[image: display:inline-block]

html

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child inline-block-child'>A</div>
  <div class='child inline-block-child'>B</div>
</div>
```

css

```css
.inline-block-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

---

**Note**: the space between these two child elements can be removed, by removing the space between the div tags:

[image: display:inline-block (no space)]

html

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child inline-block-child'>A</div><div class='child inline-block-child'>B</div>
</div>
```

css

```css
.inline-block-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

---

[image: display:flex]

html

```
<div class='parent flex-parent'>
  <div class='child flex-child'>A</div>
  <div class='child flex-child'>B</div>
</div>
```

css

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

---

[image: display:inline-flex]

html

```
<div class='parent inline-flex-parent'>
  <div class='child'>A</div>
  <div class='child'>B</div>
</div>
```

css

```css
.inline-flex-parent {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

---

[image: display:grid]

html

```
<div class='parent grid-parent'>
  <div class='child'>A</div>
  <div class='child'>B</div>
</div>
```

css

```css
.grid-parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
}
```

---

Comment: Yeah, but I heard that using `inline-block` has some compatibility issues.  Also, any advantage to using that over `float`?

Comment: Yes, `inline-block` is newer, thus your targe browsers may not yet support it (though there are many browser-specific properties and also workarounds for this). The advantage is that the containing element will wrap the elements; with `float` you'll have to add css to parent element.

Comment: Note: using `inline-block` may cause some elements to be misaligned. *I* fixed this by making sure each element had the same amount of lines of text.

Comment: I like the way you gave examples.

Answer (score 20):

keep it simple

```
<div align="center">
<div style="display: inline-block"> <img src="img1.png"> </div>
<div style="display: inline-block"> <img src="img2.png"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
}

.element-left {
  width: 94%;
}

.element-right {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div id="dB" class="element-left" }>
    <a href="http://notareallink.com" title="Download" id="buyButton">Download</a>
  </div>
  <div id="gB" class="element-right">
    <a href="#" title="Gallery" onclick="$j('#galleryDiv').toggle('slow');return false;" id="galleryButton">Gallery</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.element-left {
  flex: 2;
}

.element-right {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div id="dB" class="element-left" }>
    <a href="http://notareallink.com" title="Download" id="buyButton">Download</a>
  </div>
  <div id="gB" class="element-right">
    <a href="#" title="Gallery" onclick="$j('#galleryDiv').toggle('slow');return false;" id="galleryButton">Gallery</a>
  </div>
</div>
```