# div alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs nested inside a bigger div as

```
<div id="site-wrapper">
   <div id="user1"></div>
   <div id="user2"></div>
<div>
```

The css is

```
#site-wrapper{
    border: 1px solid;
width: 800px;
min-height: 600px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#user1{
border: 1px solid;
width: 200px;
min-height: 100px;
 }  
#user2{
border: 1px solid;
width: 200px;
min-height: 100px;
}
```

They are appearing one below the other. How do i get them on the same level at the side of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float `#user1` and `#user2`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/S6JGu/).

Answer (score 4):

Since DIVs are block elements by default, you need to "float" them to allow them to be horizontally-arranged. I've added the floats to each of the two divs below:

```
#site-wrapper{
    border: 1px solid;
width: 800px;
min-height: 600px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#user1{
border: 1px solid;
width: 200px;
min-height: 100px;
float:left;
 }  
#user2{
border: 1px solid;
width: 200px;
min-height: 100px;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: @user Why did you ask the question then? :P

Comment: I was wondering the same thing lol. Unless he meant "That's exactly the answer I was looking for."

Comment: SO isn't what it used to be :P a simple search for "div side by side" would've also yielded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938716/align-div-elements-side-by-side

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below would work:

```
#site-wrapper div {
    float : left;
}
```

Keep in mine your floated elements have fixed widths--that's important, as you may get unexpected results if you don't explicitly define the width of floated elements.

To read more about the behavior of visual formatting elements, see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the float property.

```
user1
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 200px;
min-height: 100px;
float:left;
}  
user2{
border: 1px solid;
width: 200px;
min-height: 100px;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  float:left; to the CSS for #user1

Alternately, you can add display:inline to the two user divs, but it is very likely that in the future you will need display:block on one or both of those, and so then you'd have to resort back to the float.

Comment: If you set them as inline, they'll lose all of their padding and look like one blob of DIV lines :P