# div alignment side by side

Tags: css

I have 2 nested divs as

```
 <div id="header">
   <div id="logo"></div>
   <div id="header_r"></div>
 </div>
```

The css is

```
 #header{
      border: 1px solid;
  width: 900px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
  }     
#logo{
    border: 1px solid;
width: 400px;
border-radius: 10px;
min-height: 80px;
float: left;
 }
  #header_r{
    border: 1px solid;
width: 500px;
border-radius: 10px;
min-height: 80px;
float: left;
 }
```

It gets arranged one below the other. How do I get them side by side?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798400/div-alignment-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce width for logo and header_r by 2px each because border is also included in width of an element.

Answer (score 3):

Close the tag on the header-r div

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the tag on the "header_r" div

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="logo"></div>
   <div id="header_r"></div>
 </div>
```