# Two div blocks on same line

Tags: html, css

How to center on the same "line" two div blocks?

First div:

```
<div id=bloc1><?php echo " version ".$version." Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved."; ?></div>
```

Second div:

```
<div id=bloc2><img src="..."></div>
```

Comment: Float or inline-block via CSS.

Comment: You can also use ```display : table-cell;``` and add line break where you want using ```<br>```

Comment: Related post - [Align <div> elements side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4938716/465053)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

CSS:

```
#block_container
{
    text-align:center;
}
#bloc1, #bloc2
{
    display:inline;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="block_container">

    <div id="bloc1"><?php echo " version ".$version." Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved."; ?></div>  
    <div id="bloc2"><img src="..."></div>

</div>
```

Also, you shouldn't put raw content into `<div>`'s, use an appropriate tag such as `<p>` or `<span>`.

Edit: Here is a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JDERf/).

Comment: The image is in the middle ... the text is after and right aligned

Comment: @Bertaud then you must have some other CSS/HTML interfering because the above works. See my jsFiddle demo.

Comment: I think you are right :-(  Do you know how to validate the whole html page ?

Comment: Gildor's answer is prefereable, because it also works with nested <div> tags using display:inline-block;.

Comment: I want to center `bloc1` and align `bloc2` to the right while keeping them on the same line. How can this be done?

Answer (score 64):

You can do this in many way.

> 1. Using `display: flex`

```css
#block_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="block_container">
  <div id="bloc1">Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</div>
  <div id="bloc2"><img src="..."></div>
</div>
```

> 2. Using `display: inline-block`

```css
#block_container {
    text-align: center;
}
#block_container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="block_container">
  <div id="bloc1">Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</div>
  <div id="bloc2"><img src="..."></div>
</div>
```

> 3. using `table`

```html
<div>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="bloc1">Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="bloc2"><img src="..."></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 35):

I think now, the best practice is use `display: inline-block;`

look like this demo:

```css
div {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

**EDIT (02/2021):**

Best practice now may be to using `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` on div container and `flex-basis: XX%;` on div

look like this demo:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

div {
  flex-basis: 45%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is a better answer than the accepted one, because it works for  nested <div>s too!

Comment: this is best answer than accepted coz inline-block cover margin too

Comment: nope! as soon as you make uneven widths this fails to work : https://jsfiddle.net/L8rkqzd2/

Comment: @tatsu It's true! With uneven widths, unfortunately, you need to lock same height too. 
Look if this solve your problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/0a7x3oya/1/

Answer (score 11):

You can use a HTML table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="bloc1">your content</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="bloc2">your content</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try an HTML table or use the following CSS :

```
<div id="bloc1" style="float:left">...</div>
<div id="bloc2">...</div>
```

(or use an HTML table)

Comment: Tables are for tabular data... not for presentation.

Comment: html table are also a way to present data. huh?

Comment: afterwards might want to reset formatting by `<div style={{clear: "left"}}>`

Answer (score 3):

[`diplay:flex;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) is another alternative answer that you can add to all above answers which is supported in all [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
#block_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="block_container">
  <div id="bloc1">Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</div>
  <div id="bloc2"><img src="..."></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML File

```
 <div id="container">
      <div id="bloc1">Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</div>
      <div id="bloc2"><img src="..."></div>
    </div>
```

CSS File

```
 #container
    {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #bloc1, #bloc2
    {
        display:inline;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would first is make the following CSS code:

```
#bloc1 {
   float: left
}
```

This will make `#bloc2` be inline with `#bloc1`.

To make it central, I would add `#bloc1` and `#bloc2` in a separate div. For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper { margin: 0 auto; }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="bloc1"> ... </div>
    <div id="bloc2"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that doesn't work: bloc1 is on right, bloc2 is on another line !

Answer (score 0):

Use a table inside a div.

```
<div>
   <table style='margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto'>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <div>Your content </div>
           </td>
           <td>
              <div>Your content </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Css:

```
#bloc1,
#bloc2 {
display:inline
} 

body {
text-align:center
}
```

It will make the mentioned 2 divs in the center on the same line.

Answer (score -2):

Use Simple HTML

```
<frameset cols="25%,*">
  <frame src="frame_a.htm">
  <frame src="frame_b.htm">
</frameset>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.