# Put two divs in the same line with CSS

Tags: html, css, display

I have a problem with two `div` items. As shown in the screenshot below, I want to put `PM` and `8` in the same line, so it looks like `8 PM`.

[image]

I checked others solutions and I tried to add
`display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` to the parent div, but it does not work.

My Code to render the Div:

```css
.time: {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40;
}

.period: {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.hour: {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="time">
  <div class="period">PM</div>
  <div class="hour">8</div>
</div>
```

Can I get some help?

Comment: If you want to display '8 PM,' why is the PM div before the 8 div?

Comment: What does it show when you try `display: inline`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two div blocks on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451445/two-div-blocks-on-same-line)

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Remove `:` from selectors
>
> 2) You miss `f` in `font-size`

Now use from `inline` or `inline-block` :

Method1: Use of `inline` like this :

```css
.time{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40;
}

.period{
    font-size: 10px;
    display:inline;
}

.hour {
    font-size: 10px;
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="time">
    <div class="hour">8</div>
    <div class="period">PM</div>
</div>
```

Method2: use `inline-block` like this :

```css
.time{
   height: 40px;
   width: 40;
}

.period{
    font-size: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.hour {
    font-size: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="time">
  <div class="hour">8</div>
  <div class="period">PM</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use flexbox and set it to row (or in your case row-reverse since you have them backwards)

```css
.flexcontainer {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row-reverse;
   width:40px;
   height: 40px;
   font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
<div>PM</div>
<div>8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have two typos:

   - It is `font-size` not `ont-size`.
   - You do not put a colon after CSS selectors
2. I'm not quite sure why display:inline did not work, but since it did not work
3. Use `<span>` instead of `<div>` like so

```css
.time {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.period {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.hour {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="time">
  <span class="hour">8</span>
  <span class="period">PM</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **:** from your CSS code.

HTML

```
<div class="time">
   <div class="hour">8</div>
   <div class="period">PM</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.time {
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #3279e3;
}

.period {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.hour {
  ont-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can handle this by a single div.

```
<div>
<p>8<span>PM</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left` `css` property to both `.period` and `.hour` classes as below.

```
.period {
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.hour {
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

For easiness and reducing lines of codes, you can define the `css` property one time only as below for both classes since the properties of both classes are same.

```
.period, .hour {
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set your `.time` div display to grid and set number of grid-column you want it will be like :

```css
    .time{
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      display : grid ;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    }
    .period{
      font-size: 10px;
    }
    .hour{
      font-size: 10px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="time">
      <div class="hour">8</div>
      <div class="period">PM</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a really short solution:

```css
.time {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.period: {
  ont-size: 10px;
}

.hour: {
  ont-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="time">
  <div class="hour">8</div>
  <div class="period">PM</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. Best Regards.

Comment: I suggest you put an explanation and fix the typos in the CSS that the OP also had.