# Aligning div elements side-by-side

Tags: alignment, html

I have a page on a project I'm creating for class where I wanted to align an image in the left side, with the text to the right aligned in the middle of the image.  Instead of using html elements, I decided to try an internal CSS div elements within my external CSS.  My problem is that I can't get them to align correctly vertically.  I have the horizontal alignment, but the text either appears one line above or one line below the image.  I tried the techniques included in this posting, but they didn't fix my problem.  [Align <div> elements side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938716/align-div-elements-side-by-side)

Here is my internal CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
/* left div holding the image */
#left {
width:170px;
align:left;  }

/* right div to hold the text */
#right {
margin-left: 200px;
text-align:left; }
</style>
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="content">
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<blockquote>
<div id="right">Check back soon.  <a href="mailto:TwoWiredChicksJewelry@gmail.com?subject=AlertWhenPageComplete">Click here</a> to receive an email when the site becomes available.</div><div id="left"><img src="images/construction-clipart.jpg" border="1" alt="Page under construction" /></div>
</blockquote>
</div>
```

Can you help me figure out how to make these align?  To view how it is rendering, please visit my student project site at http://www.student.nvcc.edu/home/ligomes/TwoWiredChicks/Browse.html.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I hope this helps now. All you have for the right css is:

```
#right {

    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 200px

}
```

Comment: That didn't fix the problem.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: The length is included in the external CSS and both of these elements are included in an element within the external CSS.  Would that be causing the problem?  I wasn't sure if you can nest an internal CSS into an external CSS.

Comment: Updated answer. Hope it helped.

Comment: Or you could also try `margin-top: -40px`

Comment: This was how I had it originally, but I tried it again and it doesn't seem to correct it.  More thoughts?

Comment: How about now? It seemed to wok on your website.

Comment: What browser are you using?  I have tried both Chrome and IE.  It is still rendering the same way.

Comment: That worked!  Any thoughts on how I can align it in the middle of the image instead of the top?

Comment: Change your `#right` css. `margin-top: 60px;` seems to do it. If this is what you are looking for, mark this answer as the final answer.