# asp.net button text alignment in iphone safari

Tags: asp.net, mobile-safari

My asp.net button text is expremely aligned to right. The last char is halfly not seen.

Here is the code:

```
<table style="margin:0 auto;width:300px;">
                <tr style="margin:0 auto;width:300px">
                    <td style="margin:0 auto;width:150px;">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveAndClose" onClientClick="if(!timesValidation()) return false;" style="width:125px;height:44px;font-size:30px;text-align:left;" OnClick="btnSaveAndClose_Click" runat="server" Text="Save and close" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="margin:0 auto;width:150px;">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveAndNew" onClientClick="if(!timesValidation()) return false;" style="width:150px;height:44px;font-size:30px;" OnClick="btnSaveAndNew_Click" runat="server" Text="Save and New" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with the table based layout forcing the button to the right.

I would switch to a more modern approach to page layout (div's and external CSS).

Take a look at this question and answer for an idea of how to do this.

[Align <div> elements side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938716/align-div-elements-side-by-side)