# HTML, CSS: 2 divs next to?

Tags: css, html

i just need anybodys help please :(
I'll try to put 2 divs next to but it wont work :(

Here the CSS:

```
.bookmarktrick {
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
}

.header {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 20%;
    float: none;

    padding-bottom: 15px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<div class="header">Some text</div>

<div class="bookmarktrick">Hello World</div>
```

I want that the Bookmark div is next to the header (left or right side).
The header is in the middle of the page.

Here is a Picture for understanding
http://www7.pic-upload.de/04.05.14/zjsrg7ifn4ul.png

Comment: Next to each other, you mean? `clear: both;` seems like a weird thing to do; don't you want to `float` .bookmarktrick, instead?

Comment: http://www7.pic-upload.de/04.05.14/zjsrg7ifn4ul.png like in this picture

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrsfq/ any where near it

Comment: @deim0wl - do you want them beside each other or one aligned left and the other aligned right?

Comment: @Danield i want the header in the middle (with 20% width) and the bookmarktrick div right.. but in the same height as the header div

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align <div> elements side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938716/align-div-elements-side-by-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Switch the order of the elements in the markup like so:

```
<div class="bookmarktrick">Hello World</div>
<div class="header">Some text</div>
```

2) Set `float:right` on the bookmarktrick

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/t7eC5/2/)**

Comment: I updated this answer according to the comments on the question

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use `float:left;` or `float:right;` on both elements.

Comment: it doesnt work.. :( the bookmarktrick div starts where the header div ends (from the height)