# How to change onclick text's position?

Tags: html, text, onclick

Hi guys so I'm new to all this html stuff.

Basically;

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick

When i do this the text shows up under the button. I want it next to the button (right)

How can i do that?

Comment: You need to adjust html markup to match to what you want. More detailed info you can find here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align <div> elements side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938716/align-div-elements-side-by-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you need to spend a bit more time learning about this. Realistically you'll need to use CSS to style the HTML that is output by your Javascript.

Both CodeSchool and Codecademy have great tutorials on learning the basics of HTML, CSS and Javascript. You'll need to learn these basics if you want to do this sort of thing yourself.

https://www.codeschool.com/

https://www.codecademy.com/

I've copied your example into a CodePen, which helps to show you the roles played by HTML, CSS and Javascript. As an example, the CSS could be;

http://codepen.io/tombeynon/pen/rVQvMO

```
button{
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}

#demo{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I know i need to but it's kinda a homework for me and it appears i couldn't found anything in the websites.

Comment: Added an example to try to help a bit more.

Comment: I owe you one dude. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block` to `p` tag

Try this.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
 <p id="demo" style="display:inline-block"></p>
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/9yqs14p4/

Comment: @BozaSatanAdam It will work i have update my answer. Click on the fiddle  to see the demo.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to know, that in HTML there are **inline** elements, e.g `<span>` and **block** elements, e.g `<div>`. That means, what the word says.

You can test the difference:

```
// block
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>

// inline
<span>span1</span><span>span2</span>
```

In the example is used the `<p>` tag which is a block element. Therefore
you see the text below.

`<button>` is an inline element. If you simply use a span:

```
<span id="demo"></span>
```

it works!