# Creating divs that stand side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create divs that stand side by side with and each one fill 25% of the screen in height and width. My script creates divs with 25% height and width, but they stay one below the other. My script is:

```js
   function createDiv() {
     var div_created = document.createElement("div");
     div_created.setAttribute("class", "div1");

     document.body.appendChild(div_created);
   }
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo_segundo.css">
<body>
<button onclick="createDiv()">Click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place div side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637696/how-to-place-div-side-by-side)

Comment: link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938716/align-div-elements-side-by-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.div1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add** `html,body` **style** & inside `div1` **add** `float:left;`

```
 html,body
 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }

.div1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
  float:left;
}
```

**Live Demo** **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/kw8Ljvqc/)**

**Snippet Example**

```js
function createDiv() {
  var div_created = document.createElement("div");
  div_created.setAttribute("class", "div1");
  document.body.append(div_created);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.div1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button onclick="createDiv()">Click</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `display: table;` in a wrapper div and simplify your JS:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createDiv() {
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += '<div></div>';
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    background-color: #000000;
}
#div1 div {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid green; /* green for display */
}
</style>
</head><body>
<button onclick="createDiv()">Click</button>
<div id="div1" name="div1"></div>
</body></html>
```

This adds an inner 'cell' to the `div1` wrapper div. Since the wrapper takes up the display height/width, each inner div has an 'auto' width to it (as a table `<td>` would).