# How does details tag in html with a <a> tag work

Tags: html

How to align an `<a>` tag with the `<details>` tag in the same line. 
For example i want  space with `<details>` in one row. But, if you do so the `<details>` is going to the next line.

Is there any solution?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>Some Text</a>
      <details>
        <summary></summary>
      </details>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide screenshots and actual examples. It's hard to tell what you're actually looking for but I'm guessing it's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938716/align-div-elements-side-by-side)

Comment: make it inline?

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

It makes the A behave a bit strange unless you also make it a block element

```css
a, details { display:inline-block }
a { float:left; padding-right:3px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>Some Text</a>
      <details>
        <summary>Summary</summary>
        <p>Some details</p>
      </details>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Since you are using a table, you can easily fix this

```css
td { vertical-align:top }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a>Some Text</a></td>
    <td><details>
        <summary>Summary</summary>
        <p>Some details</p>
      </details>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but on click on summary the complete text comes down. How that can be solved?

Comment: That worked !! I was wondering if i can add a link to the details tag, so on click on the arrow it should open a popup. Can i do that?

Comment: Sure. You likely want to find an example - easy to find at so. CSS or js

Comment: I added the onclick event for the <summary> tag to open a popup and that worked .. Thanks!!..