# Multiple tags Alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to align tags side to side, even if the screen width/height changes they still align? Please detail the process either its JavaScript or CSS. Preferably without frameworks, meaning plain CSS or Plain JavaScript.

Comment: You're going to need to explain your question in more detail as well as provide a [mcve]. Please see [ask]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align <div> elements side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938716/align-div-elements-side-by-side)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {text-align: center;}
p {text-align: center;}
div {text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div>This is a div.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Like this?

[Align <div> elements side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938716/align-div-elements-side-by-side)

Comment: can you do a screenshot drawing?