# How to position submit button beside each other html

Tags: html, css

I currently have 2 submit buttons that cannot be place side by side.

[image]

```
    .submit-button {
         color: #fff;
         background: #55a1ff;
         border: 0;
         outline: 0;
         width: calc(15%);
         height: 50px;
         font-size: 16px;
         text-align: center;
         cursor: pointer;
         margin-top: 70px;
         margin-left:100px;
         border-radius: 30px;
    }

    .cancel-button {
         color: #fff;
         background: #55a1ff;
         border: 0;
         outline: 0;
         width: calc(15%);
         height: 50px;
         font-size: 16px;
         text-align: center;
         cursor: pointer;
     
         margin-left:450px;
         border-radius: 30px;

    }
```

```
<div class="arrange3">
    <button type="submit" class="submit-button" name="save", value="save">Submit</button>
</div>


<div class="arrange3">
    <button type="cancel" class="cancel-button" name="cancel", value="save">Cancel Claim</button>
</div>
```

How am i suppose to place the buttons side by side. It would be great if u can provide the code to me. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align <div> elements side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938716/align-div-elements-side-by-side)

Comment: Thank you so much @ pjcunningham. It solves the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make arrange3 class display inline.

```
.arrange3{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I cant.. both are using different form action methods

Comment: I'm not sure why it shouldn't be possible. But anyway.. on the first div u can put an inline style with float: left;

Comment: Well, that's weird, I used your code exactly and it does work for me. I also noticed with the margin lefts on the buttons, if the page is too small that the buttons will wrap. Try removing the margin lefts and see if it works.

Comment: Nope it doesnt work..thanks for your help anyways