# How to "create a Div that does NOT start on a new line, after a header?"

Tags: html, css, header, division

I'm relatively new here and I feel like the solution is so simple that I am just not seeing it.

```css
    #GeneralTextBox02{ 
    background: #ddd;
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>??????? </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
  
    <h2>#1 </h2> 

    <div id="GeneralTextBox02">(Testing)</div>

    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My question is simple, in my view:
(A) I have a "#1" for a header.
(B) And then NEXT TO IT; i'd like to have my general text box. a box i can fill in with content, and right next to it will be a big ol #1.
(B.1) but the final product is NOT showing the text box next to the header of #1.
(C) id like, the ability to have a header that i can change (#1, #2, #3) and "resize #1 #2 #3 overtime" to be the same size as "whatever size the text box next to it is" and so: "i need the #1, next, to the text box."

And i feel like i'm missing something. I don't have a `<br>` or a `<p> </p>` and yet its not showing up next to one another! I'm still extremely new so i feel like it's so simple that i'm just missing it. but does anyone know how to get the text box next to the number?

-Scholah

Comment: do you mean putting everything in one line? did you try putting the h2 inside your each div?

Comment: yes! putting everything on one line! somebody modified my question and attached a link to an answer here:>>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938716/align-div-elements-side-by-side <<< and that seems to have done the trick! but idk how to answer it! thank you tho!

Comment: putting them in one div and floating your header to the left will do the trick you are saying if i understand your question correctly or else you need to use a flex box to do a trick or a grid boxes.

Comment: Yes! That worked! Thank you!!!

Comment: thats good it works for you